# PyQt, QWidget in a QTableWidget vertical header

Tags: header, pyqt, qwidget, qtableview, qtablewidget

What would be the proper way to add a QComboBox instead of a label at the third vertical header's row for example. I don't really understand how works QHeaderView actually.

Thanks for your help folks.

```
import sys
import string
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Header(QHeaderView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(Header, self).__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)

class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(Header(self))
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        self.setRowCount(3)

    self.setColumnWidth(0,100)
    self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1'])
    self.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['1','2'])

    self.combo = QComboBox(self.verticalHeader())
    self.combo.addItem('a')
    self.combo.addItem('b')

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
t = Table()
t.show()
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```